# Tkinter filedialog.askdirectory() not working in windows server

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to open a dialog box that asks for a path, the code used for that is

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() #Since I only need the filedialog and not a blank window at the back
source_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title = 'Select Source Folder')
```

This works in my windows installation, but when I run this on a windows server, the dialog box(Folder Selection box is not opening)

**Note** Windows server doesn't freeze, it just doesn't display the popup and the powershell behaves as if it is expecting an input.

**System configurations:**

Local System(Working): Python 3.6, windows 10 N (1803)

Remote System(Not Working): Python 3.6, windows Server 2016 Standard (1607)

Connecting to remote server using `mstsc`, I am happy to provide additional Information if needed.

Things I have already tried before posting:

- Restarting the windows server.
- Fresh Install of python on windows server.
- Checking Multiple times that I am running the same code.
- Only running this Isolated code on the server.

Let me know if you are able to replicate the problem, if not I might have to reset the windows server install.
P.S. Just in case, yes the server has a full fledged graphical interface, and not a command line interface.

Comment: Tried this from Win 7 mstsc to Windows Server 2008 R2, Python 3.7. Could not reproduce, filedialog loads as expected. Don't have any other Windows Server 
installations available to test unfortunately.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thanks for trying, I had to format the server and now it works, guess I will never know why it was not working.